# Modificar cores de gradiente em gráficos no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como faço para modificar as cores do gradiente de um gráfico no `ggplot`?

Tipo, não estou conseguindo colocar uma escala de cores continua entre  branco e vermelho, já tentei uma variedade de coisas mais ainda não me atendeu.

```
library('ggplot2')  
Tipo = c("Casa", "Rua", "Bairro", "Municipio")  
Freq = c(100, 150, 175, 300)  
dados = data.frame(Tipo,Freq)  

ggplot(data=dados, aes(x=Freq, y=Tipo, fill=Freq)) +  
       geom_label(label=rownames(dados), color="white", size=3) +  
       labs(x = "Frequência", y = "Tipo")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Utilize a função `scale_fill_gradient` para isto:

```
ggplot(data=dados, aes(x=Freq, y=Tipo, fill=Freq)) +  
  geom_label(label=rownames(dados), color="black", size=3) +  
  labs(x = "Frequência", y = "Tipo") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="#FFFFFF", high="#FF0000")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A maneira mais fácil de utilizá-la é definir qual cor é o limite inferior da tua escala (`low`) e qual é o limite superior (`high`). As cores são informadas no padrão RGB (**R**ed, **G**reen, **B**lue) hexadecimal. De maneira resumida, este padrão define cada cor com um código da forma `#RRGGBB`, em que

- RR é um número hexadecimal entre 00 e FF, permitindo assim 256 níveis de vermelho
- GG é um número hexadecimal entre 00 e FF, permitindo assim 256 níveis de verde
- BB é um número hexadecimal entre 00 e FF, permitindo assim 256 níveis de azul

Portanto, quando eu coloco `low="FFFFFF"`, eu estou dizendo que quero o máximo de vermelho, verde e azul na minha cor. O resultado disso é o branco, pois esta cor é a mistura de todas as outras cores.

Por outro lado, quando coloco `high="FF0000"`, eu estou dizendo que quero o máximo de vermelho e o mínimo de verde e azul na minha cor. O resultado disso é o vermelho puro.

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado.

Answer (score 10):

A minha solução é muito parecida com a do @Marcus Nunes, mas com uma diferença que me parece importante, por isso decidi também responder.
A diferença está no vetor de cores usadas na `geom_label`. Para ter contraste com o fundo as cores são ou `"red"` ou `"white"` consoante os valores de `Freq` sejam menores ou maiores que a mediana desse vetor dos `dados`.

Há ainda outra diferença mas de menor importância. A função `scale_fill_gradient` aceita os limites como strings com os nomes das cores, evitando assim ter que saber os valores haxadecimais RGB correspondentes. (Não faz mal nenhum sabê-los, já agora, é até muito útil.)

```
cols <- ifelse(dados$Freq < median(dados$Freq), "red", "white")

ggplot(data=dados, aes(x=Freq, y=Tipo, fill=Freq)) +  
  geom_label(label=rownames(dados), size=3, colour=cols) +  
  labs(x = "Frequência", y = "Tipo") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Excelente adição a respeito do contraste nos algarismos.

Comment: Show de bola, obrigado.