# Como mudar as cores do gráfico ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

O código abaixo gera um gráfico de linhas que cujas cores estão configuradas de forma automática para azul e vermelho:

```
ggplot(aes(x = factor(year), y1 = auto_course_choice, y2 = auto_hire, group=country)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = auto_course_choice, colour = "autonomy course decision")) + facet_wrap(~ country, ncol = 7) + 
  theme_bw()+
  geom_line(aes(y = auto_hire, colour = "autonomy hiring teachers")) + 
  facet_wrap(~ country, ncol = 7) + 
  theme_bw()
```

Como é possível mudar as cores das linhas geradas por `geom_line()` em um gráfico [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2)?

Comment: Olá Michelle, você precisa especificar que cores quer mudar? a cor da linha? A cor do fundo? Se for mais clara, sua pergunta tem mais chance de ser respondida.

Comment: ok, obrigada! eu quero mudar a cor das linhas do gráfico que parece estão automáticas para azul e vermelho!

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(dados)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados, 20))`? Nota: `dados` é o nome da base, por exemplo de um data.frame.

Comment: @RuiBarradas certeza que precisa disso para responder a pergunta?

Comment: @DanielFalbel Absolutamente necessário talvez não seja, posso criar um conjunto de dados. Mas já viu a cor no código acima? `colour = "autonomy hiring teachers"` não é uma variável da base de certeza absoluta.

Comment: @DanielFalbel Além disso falta o argumento `data` em `ggplot()`.

Comment: Por isso mesmo, ela está forçando a cor direto. Eu queria abrir a pergunta mesmo...

Comment: Não dá para reabrir depois que ela comentou que são as linhas geradas pelo `geom_line()`?

Comment: Ou indicar [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/306601/modificar-cores-em-gr%C3%A1ficos-no-ggplot2) como já contendo a resposta... (@DanielFalbel e @RuiBarradas)

Comment: Sim, mas precisa de 5 votos para reabrir. Eu acho que essa pergunta responde só o gradiente, o dela é uma escala categórica.

Comment: Pode usar `colour = c("blue", "red")`. Mas o que está lá não é um nome de cor. Parece ser esse o principal problema. Seja como for, vou votar para reabrir.